Check if two files are existing in SFTP using ADF
I have two files (xlsx & pdf) in sftp folder. These are the requirements I need to complete:

if two files are existing proceed to the True condition databricks notebook. If one is not present, will proceed to False condition databricks notebook.

Edited:
This is what I tried first. Used get metadata and If condition activity.
get metadata activity
If condition activity expression:
If condition activity expression
The two files are existing so I am expecting to receive the notebook in True condition, however, notebook in False condition is running.

Are you getting any error?

no error but no result as well. after successful run of if condi activity, nothing happens.

The IF condition has to be True, False, or the activity has to Fail. Which one is the case in your example?

My example is once met, the True condition will run.

I understand what you want to happen, but you said "Nothing happens", which can't be correct.

@kimchigirl, what is the value of the parameter FullPath here? Can you provide a sample of it?

I changed for a while the requirement. What I am trying for now first is to run specific databricks notebook if the condition is True or false.

Do you already know the file names before the pipeline run?

Yes. I already know the file names. I just want to check if the file types are existing, if so, proceed to true condition and if one of the files is not existing in sftp, it will fall to false condition.

I have tried your expression, and I got similar results.

Here, in your expression, you are checking .xlsx and .pdf strings existing or not in the array. But these are only substrings of each item in the Child items array. The contains() for an array only gives true when the given total string is in the array which is not in your case. To achieve your requirement, try the below approach.
First, in the Get meta data activity, give the path till only your source folder. Don't include the file name. Add Child items property.

As you already know the file name without extension, now use the below expression in the if activity.
@and(contains(string(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems),concat('DA_12345','.pdf')), contains(string(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems),concat('DA_12345','.xlsx')))

This expression first converts the total child items array into a string and then checks whether both file names are in the string or not. I have given the file names as it is in the expression, you can use your parameters.

Now, it will work as expected.

You can also try exists option in the Get meta data activity by giving the file name. This option gives true if the given file name exists in the given folder and false if not exists.

But you need to use two Get meta data activities for this, in which one is for .pdf and another is for .xlsx. After both activities, you can directly use this expression in the if activity.
@and(activity('Get Metadata1').output.exists,activity('Get Metadata2').output.exists)


Hi, thank you so much. This solved my problem for a week. I tried the 1st approach, used @and(contains(string(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems),concat('DA_12345','.pdf')), contains(string(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems),concat('DA_12345','.xlsx'))).                           I just wanna know what if idk the filenames, i tried just @and(contains(string(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems),concat('DA_','.pdf')), contains(string(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems),concat('DA_','.xlsx'))).   but the result is not my expectation.

Hi, I already get the right expression. @and(contains(string(activity('GetFileList_MFT').output.childItems),'.pdf'), contains(string(activity('GetFileList_MFT').output.childItems),'.xlsx'))

I thought to give the same. Good to know that you have solved yourself : ).

Thanks to Rakesh Govindula for the solution. I tried this one if I know the filenames from sftp:
@and(contains(string(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems),concat('DA_12345','.pdf')), contains(string(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems),concat('DA_12345','.xlsx')))  

This is also working if you just want to check the files if contains specific string on the files:
@and(contains(string(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems),'.pdf'), contains(string(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems),'.xlsx'))

